# How do you reload your environment while using script/console?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, models, reload, script-console

I think I have seen Ryan Bates do it one of his screencasts, but I can't find it.

I believe there is a command you can run while in script/console that lets you reload your models (if say you have made a change) so that you dont have to exit and then recall the console.

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Just use:

```
reload!
```

However, do note that this **won't** reflect the changes on the models that are already instantiated in your console. To reflect changes in already instantiated models, you may visit [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5428421/636762).

Answer (score 1):

If you are using rspec use

```
load 'some_class.rb'
```