# Helper method doesn't reload by `reload!` in rails console

Tags: ruby-on-rails, helper, rails-console

I have a helper method like this:

```
module PostsHelper
  def foo
    "foo"
  end
end
```

And in rails console I check the function, then change the text `"foo"` to `"bar"`, then `reload!` the console, but `helpers.foo` still doesn't return `"bar"`.

Maybe Helper object is already created in the console like this post, I'm not sure about that.
[Rails Console: reload! not reflecting changes in model files? What could be possible reason?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5427596/rails-console-reload-not-reflecting-changes-in-model-files-what-could-be-poss)

Only I want to know is how to play with helper method in rails console. Could you show me how to do it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are correct that `helper` represents an object that is already instantiated, and therefore not affected by calls to `reload!`.  The `helper` method in the console is defined as:

```
def helper
  @helper ||= ApplicationController.helpers
end
```

The first time you call `helper`, it will memoize the `ApplicationController` helpers.  When you call `reload!`, the `ApplicationController` class (and it's helpers) are reloaded, but the `helper` method is still looking at an old instance.

Instead of using the `helper` method, you can call `ApplicationController.helpers` directly, and you will see your changes after running `reload!`:

```
> helper.foo
# => "foo"
> ApplicationController.helpers.foo
# => "foo"
> # Change the return value of PostsHelper from "foo" to "bar"
> reload!
> helper.foo
# => "foo"
> ApplicationController.helpers.foo
# => "bar"
```

EDIT

Starting with Rails 5, this will no longer be an issue.  A [PR was merged](https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/21978) to remove memoization from the `helper` console method.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you have a helper module like the following:

```
module CarsHelper

  def put_a_car_in(location)
    if location == "your car"
      puts "So you can drive while you drive!"
    end
  end

end
```

Fire up a Rails console, and to create the helper-helper, all you have to do in include the module:

```
>> include CarsHelper # It is not necessary to include module
=> Object

>> helper.put_a_car_in("your car") # simply write helper.your_method_name
So you can drive while you drive!
```

`reload!` is not working I tried too.  You have to `quit` from `rails console` and again have to start rails c to check changes..I hope it helps you..