# Rails 5 scope issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

In rails 5 with Postgresql, I'm writing a scope to select Status items by date. My model is:

```
class Status < ApplicationRecord
  scope :in_month, ->(date){where("status_date = ?", date) if date.present?}
end
```

However, in `rails console`, I'm getting the following error when trying to use the scope.
```

```
2.4.0 :010 > Status.in_month("2018-06-01")
  Status Load (11.7ms)  SELECT  "statuses".* FROM "statuses" WHERE (status.status_date = '2018-06-01') LIMIT $1  [["LIMIT", 11]]
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "status"
LINE 1: SELECT  "statuses".* FROM "statuses" WHERE (status.status_da...
                                                    ^
: SELECT  "statuses".* FROM "statuses" WHERE (status.status_date = '2018-06-01') LIMIT $1
```

Note that for some reason, it's trying to access table "status", not "statuses".

What the heck am I doing wrong? This is pretty much straight out of the RailsGuide.

**EDIT & "fix"**

Humph... apparently the Rails console was in a bad state. I restarted the console after the comments below and found that my query worked perfectly. Note that the quotes *are* required for this format of the WHERE clause and that `statuses` is a correct pluralization of `status`.

And after restarting, the `where(status_date: date)` format described by praga2050 worked, as did the `where("statuses.status_date = ?", date)` suggested by Kedarnag Mukanahallipatna.

Lesson learned: `reload!` doesn't reload changes in models; you have to restart the console for Model changes to be recognized. See this SO answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5428421/446464

Comment: Is that the whole `Status` class? Anything going on in `ApplicationRecord`? That scope shouldn't be adding any table prefixes at all.

Comment: Can you try `scope :in_month, ->(date){where("`statuses`.status_date = ?", date) if date.present?}
`

Comment: Make sure you enclose `statuses` within ``

Comment: @KedarnagMukanahallipatna - you have an extra space in your sample, but with that fix it works as well - see my edits.

Answer (score -1):

I think you missed the point of naming conventions in rails.

> Model class names are singular, and will map automatically to the plural database table name.

According to this, you can change your model name to `statuses`.

Or set a table name to use in the rails model:

```ruby
class Status < ApplicationRecord
  self.table_name = 'status'

  scope :in_month, ->(date) { where(status_date: date) if date.present? }
end
```

Comment: Well.. "statuses" is the plural of "status" and you can see that Rails correctly recognized that as the first part of their SQL statement is `SELECT  "statuses".* FROM "statuses" WHERE...`. The pluralization failed in the WHERE clause.

Answer (score -2):

I am not sure why you are putting string inside the Where clause

```
scope :in_month, ->(date){where("status_date = ?", date) if date.present?}
```

Should be change like below.

Below one should work for you.

```
scope :in_month, ->(date){where(status_date: date) if date.present?}
```

Comment: The string format is explicitly described in the Ruby on Rails Guide (https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#scopes) section 14.2. Yours is an alternative approach and fails with the same error.